# Building a session using `isabelle` vs jEdit

Tags: isabelle, jedit

I've been working in an Isabelle 2019 session which has grown a bit large, and at some point I wasn't able to build it anymore using `isabelle build` in my 8G RAM machine. Nevertheless, when I open the main theory file using jEdit (running `isabelle jedit -d .`), the session is built with no problems.

> How can I tune the building process so it works as smoothly as the graphical interface?

Next, I give some more details.

The main symptom is that the Poly/ML process stalls at some point; it doesn't really fail but does not terminate within a reasonable amount of time (~20min, when a successful build would take 3' in my computer).

Amidst of the development, adjusting using `ML_OPTIONS` to `"--minheap 5500"` was enough to solve this, but afterwards we decided to split the session in two (no more code added, just a change in the ROOT file) and after that no further adjustment solved the issue. On the other hand, a machine with 16G RAM builds with no problem without any further setting.

**EDIT.** I've checked the options used by jEdit; those relevant (I believe) are `--minheap 500  --gcthreads 0` (the last being a default). I tried with these with no success. I also noted that the build command has a distinct `--eval Command_Line.tool0 (fn () => (Build.build "/tmp/isabelle-pedro/buildNNNNNNNNNNNNN"))` option, where `NNNNNNNNNNNNN` are some numbers.

Comment: Perhaps this is related to this [old Poly/ML behaviour](https://polyml.inf.ed.ac.narkive.com/wb7p8r1B/heap-does-not-grow-up-to-maxheap)

Comment: I recommend asking such questions on the isabelle-users mailing list as well. The Isabelle maintainers (who are probably the best people to answer this) tend to be much more active there than on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice by @ManuelEberl, I asked this question in the [isabelle-users list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/listinfo/cl-isabelle-users), and the point seems to be that the building process used by the PIDE (jEdit) is not as parallel-intensive as that of the `isabelle build` command. All the information in this answer was provided by [M. Wenzel on the list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2020-February/msg00026.html). I quote:

> both PIDE and build are using multiple threads by default, but the
>   overall profile of the parallel application comes out quite differently. E.g.
>   in PIDE proofs are only parallel in terminal positions (e.g. `by`).
>
> You can also try this:
>
> `isabelle build -o parallel_proofs=0`
>
> I.e. multithreading is enabled, but proofs are not forked.

This seems to be the setting I was looking for.

For those that (like myself) have had a limited exposure to the `isabelle` tool wrapper, the command

```
isabelle options -l
```

will show a full list of options of the whole Isabelle system.